# DNN Register link not showing

Tags: dotnetnuke

The Register link at top of our DotNetNuke site is not showing. Only the icon is showing.

This is the code from the .ascx file

```
      <div class="login-style">
        <em class="fa fa-user"></em><dnn:USER runat="server" id="dnnUSER" CssClass="login" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<em class="fa fa fa-lock"></em><dnn:LOGIN runat="server" id="dnnLOGIN" CssClass="login" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<dnn:LANGUAGE runat="server" id="dnnLANGUAGE"  showMenu="False" showLinks="True" />
```

Here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image]

The default registration page has been set in site behavior. (Note, this is a custom page with our own registration module which works on other portals).

I have also looked at the language file:

[image]

This is what the HTML looks like when I inspect it:

[image]

Comment: Is public registration enabled on the portal? This is disabled by default. And if it is the link will not show (I think).

Comment: You are correct. The setting is under security options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Portal Registration must be set to anything other than "None" in order for the registration link to appear.